# Getting error 'Property 'accounts' does not exist on type 'typeof google'' when using Google identity services with react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-identity

I am trying to implement authentication using Google in react as below.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id:
        "62032923843-508a2loa4eef8eo8kjma93m6iqekbdp.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      callback: handleCallBackResponse,
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("logInWithGoogleDiv"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
    );
  }, []);
```

I am unfortunately getting the error `Property 'accounts' does not exist on type 'typeof google'.` . I have google maps package installed in my project too.

I tried disabling Eslint for that line causing the error but that didnt fix it.
Partaining that i have a few questions,

1. Is there an npm package to handle google identity services authentication in a react way. Currently everything other than the error is fine but i was wondering if there was a simpler way than running vanilla Js code inside useeffect.
2. Is there a way i can customize my `renderButton` to fit my own personal style? Googles is fine but is there a way to implement something more consistent with my brand
3. How can i get rid of the typescript error?

Comment: google will stop login api in javascript ny march 2023. It is requested to use the Google identity service api. You can find it here https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#readme . This is the official npm repo. There are some "react" google identity service packages (eg https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth) but not maintained by google.
Google announcement for login api discontinuing : https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/gis-jsweb-authz-migration.html

Comment: you can use the google-auth-library npm package,to handle google identity services authentication in react.check this npm [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library)